# Code Organization with Multiple Related Projects

Tags: php, wordpress, project-organization

I'm working on a website project using WordPress that requires a few custom plugins. I want to keep the plugins modular, but a few of them require similar functionality. So, I find myself with conflicting goals:

- Make each plugin self-contained and modular
- Don't repeat code

For example, I have a need in two different plugins to output `<select>` elements based on a list of terms and some arguments. I wrote a function to accomplish this, but should I duplicate the function in both plugins? That seems like a maintenance nightmare, but if I don't, one plugin will depend on the other in a pretty arbitrary way. Is there some clever solution to this that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you planning on making these plugins public or keeping them within your projects only? If the latter, I would personally put them into some sort of lib/shared folder and simply load them into the plugin.

Comment: These will be private plugins for just this project. The lib folder is an interesting idea. It would still be a dependency, but it wouldn't have to be a separate plugin. Where in the WordPress file system organization would you recommend keeping the lib folder (maybe right under wp-content)?

Comment: It's completely up to you, but I generally put my libraries in a folder outside of the projects themselves; i.e: /var/www/lib - then either modify php.ini or set a php_flag to add the new include path, or if easier just require/include them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the duplicate code. In particular, consider the number of functions and their length. If both plugins share only a couple formatting methods, it's not such a big deal to duplicate that code in order to keep the plugins self-contained.

If the duplicate code is getting pretty hefty, start thinking about doing one of the following:

1. Merge the plugins into a single plugin. Only do this if the two plugins fit into the same problem space. Take a good hard look at the plugins. There's a chance that what made them seem separate before was illusory and the fundamental behaviors are closely related.
2. Extract the duplicate code into a third plugin which is a dependency of each of the plugins that share the code. Only do this if the duplicate code is related and make sense as a plugin.